# Category Page in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I have a `category.html` page that will loop through a certain category of posts.

```
{% for post in site.categories.tech %}
```

What I want to display is from the `index.html` page, when the user clicks

```
{{ post.categories }}
```

Which is generated from a loop that displays all of the posts.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
```

I need that `{{ post.categories }}` variable to replace the `.tech` in the `categories.html` like this

```
{% for category in site.categories.{{ post.categories }} %}
```

I don't know how to pass the variable from `index.html` to `categories.html`

Answer (score 0):

Site categories is an object where each key is the category name. So

```
{{ site.categories }}
```

Outputs something like this:

```
{
  "Category name" => [#, #, #, #, #, #, #],
  "Another category name" => [#, #, #, #, #, #, #],
  ...
}
```

Therefore, square brackets should do it. So if in the front matter of your index.html you have

```
---
categories: tech
---
```

The code below will render all your posts under tech category.

```
{% for post in site.categories[post.categories] %}
  {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course this won't work if you have multiple categories in the front matter, but I don't know your use case.

Comment: How can I pass the variable that was clicked from index.html. If the user clicked tech, how can I pass it to categories.html and place the value inside [post.categories]

Comment: I don't understand what "clicked variable" means. Please post an example of how are you defining that variable in `index.html`

Comment: <a href ="{site.baseurl}/categories">{{post.categories}}</a>

Comment: Post.categories will be passed to the next page.